# Sending video to server with data using retrofit

Tags: android

I am using retrofit to upload image (base64 String) with data to server. Now i can send video or image depending on condition so i wanted to know how is it possible to upload it since video is much heavier. How do i upload video on retrofit with my other data. My previous method to send data with image was:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(URLParam.USER_ID, user.getId());
params.put(URLParam.MEDIA, mBase64String);

@Headers({"Accept: application/json", "Content-Type:application/json"})
@POST("/v1/address")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadPost(@Body Map<String, Object> params);
```

How do i send video now

Answer (score 2):

Retrofit interface method would look like this..

```
@Multipart
@POST("/your url/")
Call<ResultObject> uploadVidToServer(@Part MultipartBody.Part video);
```

> Send the file in multipart so that you can **handle the progress dialog** ...for better UI

**Then make the retrofit call like this :-**

```
File videoFile = new File(pathToVideoFile);
    RequestBody videoBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*"), videoFile);
    MultipartBody.Part vFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video", videoFile.getName(), videoBody);
```

`pathToVideoFile` is the **string path of your file**

> Finally make the call

```
Call<ResultObject>  uploadVideo = vInterface.uploadVidToServer(vFile);
uploadVideo .enqueue........
```

**Remember** :-

1. Create the **requestBody** from your **VideoFile that you want to upload.**
2. Create MutlipartBody.Part object from the **RequestBody object.**
3. Then make the call.

Comment: i haven't tried it yet but i also need to send other data, like caption, creater etc, so how do i handle that part?

Comment: send body too along with it... `@Body params`

Comment: sorry i don't understand what address should i give, when it was an image i only had to send base64 string and server side used to handle it and save it, but what do i do in this case and what is the role of server side in this

Comment: well? still waiting for the answer

Comment: i havent done any server side implementation...as of yet..if i go through it i will surely update..